# How to handle error when using camera if another app open camera flutter

Tags: flutter, camera

My app using camera but another app using my camera like video call coming like messenger .
and my app crash . and i dont know how to handle this Exception.
I use package camera.

I need the help of the experts. Thanks

[image]

I have try this code to listener the error but nothing can be catch.

```
  cameraController.addListener(() {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }
      if (cameraController.value.hasError) {
        showInSnackBar(
            'Camera error ${cameraController.value.errorDescription}');
      }
    });
```

Comment: if you read the error code, it says function not implemented

Comment: what should i do ?@JAMSHAID

Answer (score 0):

you can handle with something like cathing the error

```
.catchError((Object e) {
      if (e is CameraException) {
        switch (e.code) {
          case 'CameraAccessDenied':
            print('User denied camera access.');
            break;
          default:
            print('Handle other errors.');
            break;
        }
      }
```

Comment: I have try it but it can not catch the error